# Uniswap Indexing Problem

Tags: solidity, uniswapv3

I’ve scoured the internet on this issue, and have talked to a number of solidity engineers who have worked with Uniswap pairing code. I’ve put some thought into it myself, and presenting what I believe to be an interesting solution that I have not seen talked about; see Medium article titled [Uniswap Indexing Problem](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/the-uniswap-indexing-problem-8078b8b110fc); in article you'll find:

- Uniswap Indexing Problem (defined)
- Cover the Naive approach, the Uniswap V3 approach, and finally compare against our Indexing Approach

Indexing Problem:

[image]

Uniswap V3 approach:
[image]

---

**Oct 13: Edit Update (as per comment below)**

Regarding the Uniswap indexing problem, the question posed in the article is:

Regarding determining the value of Uniswap liquidity positions; are there other simpler ideas worth exploring (ie, beyond the Uniswap v3 approach) such as the indexed approach posed in the article?

---

Objective feedback, or thoughts on this problem are welcome ... thx!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question.

Comment: Apologies; the question was posed in the article; however I just surfaced it

Comment: You should rephrase this post as a question and then post a separate answer to it.

Comment: A colleague of mine also suggested I do this; thx

Comment: Perhaps, a site like https://ethresear.ch/ will be better for this type of open questions.

Answer (score 0):

Indexed approach:

[image]

This approach is essentially a mathematical representation of what would occur in the contract code if one where to liquidate a position (delta L) in the the pool.